# How to send a interview reminder to recruiter?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, email

I had recently met a company HR staff at a career fair that was very interested in hiring me and had taken down my contact details. They said that they will call or send me an email to arrange for an interview within 3 working days. But it's been 5 days and I still haven't heard from them.

So I am thinking to send an email to their HR department to inquire/remind on the interview. And there is a problem, I only know the pronunciation of the lady's name who had spoken to me at the fair, don't even know its spelling. Wondering how can i write it politely.

Comment: What is the pronounciation?

Comment: Also, are you planning to write to HR or to the recruiter itself? If it is HR it should not matter you dont know that persons name

Comment: Hi Gray, the pronunciation is Genie/Jinny/Ginny. And sorry that I had given the wrong info, it is the company's HR crew that I met at the fair.

Comment: Ok. Most probably is Ginny (as Ginny, Ginerva, Weasley in Harry Potter lol), havent seen or heard the others... ok, even though it was the HR crew that approached you the email will be to the HR department in general, so not necessarily it will be Ginny the one replying. I will still go with my answer, so the letter is intended to anyone in HR...editing my post to reflect your edits

Comment: Have you tried to find her on LinkedIn? Direct contact would generally be better than just sending an email to the company.

Comment: @GrayCygnus Also Jeanie or even Jenny depending on the accent of the speaker.

Comment: @mkennedy yes the accent is also important, as it could be also those names you way. Either way, the best option should be to use *to whom it may concern*

Comment: Thanks for all the input, really appreciate. Had contacted them and waiting for the company to confirm interview date/time.

Answer (score 2):

You mention that the mail will be sent to HR department, rather than the individual recruiter, therefore you should not need to know its name, you could address them something like:

> **To whom it may concern:**
>
> Greetings. I was recently approached by one of your recruiters at «that job fair». We were both interested in the prospect of each other and discussed about arranging an interview. If you are ok with this please feel free to reply so we can further arrange that meeting.
>
> Sincerely, «your name»

**Edit:** If you are sure her name was Ginny you could modify the email like this:

> I was recently approached by one of your recruiters, «Ms. or Mrs.» Ginny if I recall correctly, at «that job fair»...

---

In that case I would also attach my Resume and any other relevant information. If you were given a business presentation card (which I doubt from what you say) you could also add that as a "proof" that you were indeed approached by the recruiter.

**Future suggestion:** Try to always give and receive business cards (or other things like LinkedIn) as you never know when they will be handy.

Answer (score 1):

It's okay to write in your email that you don't know how to spell the person's name you briefly met at a fair. I would just acknowledge you aren't positive of the spelling since you never exchanged business cards. Trust me, nobody will remember that.